# Using fetch with react-excel-workbook

Tags: excel, reactjs, export

My problem is that Excel Export is exporting data to Excel before fetching is completed.

**What I want to achieve:** Fetch data when the button is clicked, then after all the data is fetched, export the data to excel. **NB** I do not want to fetch data when the component is rendered for the first time.

This is only one of my attempts:

```
class ExcelExport extends React.Component {
  getDataForExport = () => {
    get('/uri')
      .then((response) => response.items)
      .catch((error) => []);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Workbook element={<input type="button" value="Excel Export" />}>
        <Workbook.Sheet data={() => this.getDataForExport()} name="Sheet A">
        <Workbook.Column label="Foo" value="foo"/>        
        </Workbook.Sheet>      
      </Workbook>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem would be to use the component state to store your data. So lets assume the call to get in your getDataForExport function returns data when the fetch is completed (the promise is resolved). In the then() call you could assign that data to the state like so:

```
class ExcelExport extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: null }
  }

  getDataForExport = () => {
    get('/uri')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ data: response });
      })
      .catch((error) => []);
  };

  ...
}
```

Then in your render function, you could add a button that triggers the data fetching and then you check whether this.state.data is null or whether some data is included and render different stuff depending on that:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Workbook element={<input type="button" value="Excel Export" onClick={this.getDataForExport.bind(this)} />}>
      {this.state.data || 
        <Workbook.Sheet data={this.state.data} name="Sheet A">
          <Workbook.Column label="Foo" value="foo"/>        
        </Workbook.Sheet>}
      </Workbook>
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried this too, but then I have to somehow trigger a fake click event to the Workbook's <ipnut /> after the data is fetched. The reason for this is that I think the click event on Workbook's <input> fires the excel export.

Comment: Unfortunately no. But i think the problem is that the react-excel-workbook npm module's Workbook tries to export its children (Workbook.Sheet) right away when you click the button. But thank you so much for your suggestion